# Showing the range of a function

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The function $f:\mathbb{Z}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ is defined by

$$f(n)=\begin{cases}3n+2\quad \text{if $n$ is even}\\ 2n+3\quad \text{if n is odd.}\end{cases}$$
Prove that the range of $f$ is $\{m\in\mathbb{Z}|m\equiv 1,2,5,8 \ \text{or} \ 9 \pmod {12}\}$

I wasn't sure of a nice way to show this, so I just considered when $n = 2k$,
$f(n) = 6k+2$.
Then I found this modulo $12$ by considering when $k\equiv 0,1,2,3,\ldots,11$ mod $12$.
This seemed to alternate from $2$ to $8$.

Then I considered when $n=2\ell +1$, and $\ell\equiv 0,1,2,\ldots,11$ mod $12$ and found the other results needed.

However, the solutions did the exact same thing, except they considered when $k\equiv 0,1,2$ and $\ell \equiv 0,1,2$ both modulo $3$... not $12$.
Why does this work?

Comment: Did "they" really consider $\ell$ in mod $3$? Not in mod $4$?

Comment: "This question has not received enough attention" doesn't really tell us what you need, beyond the answers that had already been posted before you set the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

Note that $6k\equiv0\bmod6$, so $6k\equiv0{\rm\ or\ }6\bmod{12}$, so $6k+2\equiv2{\rm\ or\ }8\bmod{12}$.

Also, $4\ell\equiv0\bmod4$, so $4\ell\equiv0,4,{\rm\ or\ }8\bmod{12}$, 
so $4\ell+5\equiv5,9,{\rm\ or\ }1\bmod{12}$.

Answer (score 1):

Since they're asking for a result modulo $12$, I would've gone for a more direct approach, like so:

$(3)(4) = 12$, so for the even cases, work modulo $4$. An even number $n$ satisfies $n \equiv 0,2 \pmod 4$. So $3n+2 = 2,8 \pmod{12}$.

$(2)(6) = 12$, so for the odd cases, work modulo $6$. An odd number $m$ satisfies $m \equiv 1,3,5 \pmod 6$. So $2n+3 \equiv 5,9,13 \equiv 5,9,1 \pmod{12}$.

So the complete range is $1,2,5,8,9 \pmod{12}$ as required.

Answer (score 0):

I would just handle each of the 12 cases individually (the values actually in the range can be combined easily). So you are left with a few proofs by contradiction. Perhaps you'll see how to combine some of those as well, as you go along.